# Ignore a file temporarily until it changes

Tags: git

I have many files in my workspace with small changes that I'll never want to commit, but I want to know when I add new changes in them.

- Example 1:
  A `Makefile` that uses `lerna`, but since I almost never use and it don't want to install it globally, I have replaced `lerna` with `npx lerna` in my local version.
  I should not commit that, and I can't ignore the file because I need to track any other change I do in it.
- Example 2:
  A file that contains a link to the backend API, that every developer sets with a different IP address, based on his home network.
- Example 3:
  A dockerfile that sets an environment variable into the container for a public key that is different for every developer.

I have many others.

As a result, browsing my git changes takes time because the git status is cluttered with many unwanted files.

- Solution 1: **`.gitignore`**

This is not a valid solution because if I change something other than that to the makefile or the dockerfile, I want to know the file is different and I need to commit the new change.

- Solution 2: **`git update-index --assume-unchanged`**

`git update-index --assume-unchanged file`
then
`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged file`

This is not a valid solution because if I mark the makefile or the dockerfile as 'assume unchanged' and I do an important modification, then the file won't show up in the git status unless I remember I needed to apply `--no-assume-unchanged` to it.

I'm looking for a solution that would basically hide the file from my local changes while it stays the exact same. Then, if I change the content, it is shown again to remind me I have done a new modification inside it.

How can I do that?

Comment: Er, this is what Git does. It tracks changes in files. Unchanged files can’t be committed.

Comment: "this is what Git does. It tracks changes in files" => Sure, but what I want is the exact opposite, I want git NOT to track some files (until they change)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a solution that would basically hide the file from my
> local changes while it stays the exact same. Then, if I change the
> content, it is shown again to remind me I have done a new modification
> inside it.

This is what Git does *by default* for content that is part of the latest commit.

The solution is to commit your local changes. You can use a private local branch which you continually rebase onto the "official" branch whenever it is updated.

Comment: "The solution is to commit your local changes": please read the 3 examples in my post. Those are things you do not want to commit because that would break the workspace of all other teammates.

Comment: That's why I suggested to use a *private local* branch (which implies that you don't push it). You do not break anything for your teammates if you only commit it in your local repository. Note that commit != push.

Comment: Even if you push it, if it's not in the main branch it will not affect your teammates other than they can *see* what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I do not think this is a situation git should solve, but here a solution, probably too complex for this case.

The idea is to have a snapshot folder where you keep a copy of the files you want to ignore (until there is no change). This folder must be ignored so, inside `.gitignore`:

```
snapshot/
```

supposing you have a `Dockerfile` in the root folder, you create the file `snapshot/Dockerfile` with the same content. Obviously the `Dockerfile` is not ignored because you still want to detect changes, but you also want it to be excluded from `git status` output. Starting from the last one, the easiest way to do it is to create a local alias like this one

```
git config alias.filter-status '!git status | grep -Ev ".*(Dockerfile|other_pattern_to_ignore).*"'
```

Calling it with

```
git filter-status
```

This alias shows every line of `git status` except for those that match the pattern specified. It gives you the output you want, unless some git description match your pattern of course. The only thing you lose is colors.

Now the last part: how to always exclude `Dockerfile` only if it did not change? Here is where the `snapshot` folder comes into play: first add a `pre-commit` hook that is going to unstage the `Dockerfile` (and all the files to exclude) with

```
git restore --staged Dockerfile
```

unless `Dockerfile` and `snapshot/Dockerfile` are different. In this case you do not unstage it because you want to commit those changes, and you also need to update the snapshot version with the new `Dockerfile`. The downside is evident when other developers have to `pull` changes of `Dockerfile`: they must remember to update their `snapshot` folder with their merged version.

By the way, I am not sure it is a working solution, one thing for sure: I would not solve it with git. For example, about the `Dockerfile`, can't you use an `.env` file that you gitignore?